# selecting images as per specific index values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have an array containing images of data as follows.

```
print(np.shape(input_data_transformed))
```

> (120, 120, 1, 589)

Here `input_data_transformed` is NumPy array having 589 images stored in it. Each image is `120x120` in size with a single channel.

I have another NumPy array called index array as follows.

```
index_array=np.array([  8,   9,  10,  11, ..............., 584, 585, 586])
```

I want to select images from `input_data_transformed` as per the index values in `index_array`

So the `final_filtered_data` should contain only those images data, the index of which is given in the `index_array`

```
final_filtered_data=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your dimensions are in the wrong order. You could `transpose` and then just index on the first axis:

```
input_data_transformed.transpose(3,2,0,1)[index_array]
```

---

Checking with an example:

```
a = np.random.rand(120, 120, 1, 589)
index_array=np.array([  8,   9,  10,  11, 584, 585, 586])

a.transpose(3,2,0,1)[index_array].shape
# (7, 1, 120, 120)
```